# Batch file convert comma delimited to fixed length

Tags: batch-file, text-files

How to convert a text file to a fixed length file:

Here is my code attempt and the sample text file.

```
del answer.txt

@ECHO on
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cls
set space=  
set var

:: loop through records
for /f "tokens=1-6 skip=1 delims=," %%a in (comma3.txt) do (
echo tokens %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
set var=%%a%space%%%b%space%%%c%space%%%d%%e%%f
echo var %var%
echo %var% >> answer.txt
)
endlocal
pause
```

Input:

```
1116559,P1303251287,20130325225906CD,13013822,1,0000
1104220,P1303250282,20130325070119CD,,1,0000
1064743,P1303251094,20130325191600CD,,0,0000
1100819,P1303250369,20130325091722CD,,0,0000
1101405,P1303250051,20130325010740CD,,0,0000
```

Desired output:

```
1116559   P1303251287   20130325225906CD   13013822   1   0000
1104220   P1303250282   20130325070119CD              1   0000
1064743   P1303251094   20130325191600CD              0   0000
1100819   P1303250369   20130325091722CD              0   0000
1101405   P1303250051   20130325010740CD              2   0000
```

Note:

The `set var` command does not store the variables.

Help GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Do you have powershell installed?  Powershell can format text similar to `printf`.  If powershell isn't an option, it might still be possible to space-fill some variables to simulate fixed-width columns.

Comment: I am sure I have Powershell but have never done anything with it. If it is an easy, robust option I will start educationg myself on that product. I see it is frequently referenced in these sites.

Comment: See my answer below then.  (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
set columnsizes=10 14 19 11 4 4
DEL answer.txt 2>nul

:: loop through records
for /f "delims=" %%a in (comma3.txt) do (
SET "result="
SET line=%%a
CALL :process %columnsizes%
)
ECHO.======================================
TYPE answer.txt
ECHO.======================================
PAUSE 
GOTO :eof

:process
REM IF "%1"=="" echo %result%>>answer.txt ECHO %result%&GOTO :eof
IF "%1"=="" echo %result%>>answer.txt&GOTO :eof
SET "column="
:colloop
IF NOT DEFINED line GOTO endcol
SET ch1=%line:~0,1%
SET line=%line:~1%
IF NOT "%ch1%"=="," SET column=%column%%ch1%&GOTO colloop
:endcol
SET column=%column%                           x
CALL SET result=%result%%%column:~0,%1%%
SHIFT
GOTO process
```

This should crack the problem.

The `FOR` loop assigns the contents of each line to `line` in turn. The routine `:process` analyses the aline and builds each column, character-by-character until it finds a comma. It then adds a large number of spaces to the end of the line - the "x" will be lopped off in the next statement and it's a litle dificult to show trailing spaces on lines (and some editors throw them away unprompted)

The `CALL SET` line uses a parser characteristic. Suppose `result` is currently `abcd` and `column` is `123  ..manyspaces..  x` and %1 is 5. The parser processes the line by replacing any %var% by its current value, then CALLs it, so what is CALLed is

```
SET result=abcd  +%+%column:~0,5+%
```

without the +s of course - they're to show how the parser sees the code.

So that neatly lops off the unwanted trailing spaces and the x in `column`; the SHIFT removes the first element from the parameter list provided to `:process` and the next column is processed until all have been done and there are no parameters left. Write out the `result`, and we're done...

Comment: Well that is VERY close. However, my answet.txt file has the result duplicated in each row with the word ECHO insterted between them: 1116559 P1303251287 20130325225906CD 13013822 1 0000 ECHO 1116559 P1303251287 20130325225906CD 13013822 1 0000...I suspect it has to do with the loop back to the last line "GOTO process" which causes the result to be added back to itself.

Comment: Well, I've REM'd out the line that was causing the problem - the correct line now follows it. The extra ECHO... on the line was supposed to ECHO the line to the screen during prooftesting, but the '&' that should hvae been before it went on holidays. Now fixed.

Comment: THAT is one sweet solution! I am extremely appreciative of your efforts. Thank you to the others for thier suggestions. I am also embarking on Powershell self-tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner to solve all your problems.  :)

```
>answer.txt powershell "Get-Content comma3.txt | %{'{0,-10}{1,-14}{2,-19}{3,-11}{4,-4}{5}' -f $_.split(',')}"
```

If you're putting this into a batch script, be sure to replace `%` with `%%` in that line.

**Contents of answer.txt:**

```
1116559   P1303251287   20130325225906CD   13013822   1   0000
1104220   P1303250282   20130325070119CD              1   0000
1064743   P1303251094   20130325191600CD              0   0000
1100819   P1303250369   20130325091722CD              0   0000
1101405   P1303250051   20130325010740CD              0   0000
```

**A feeble explanation:**

Someone more comfortable with powershell can probably explain this better than I, as it took a bunch of trial and error for me to compose that line.  But basically, as I understand it, it means as follows:

- Send the output of a powershell command to `answer.txt`
- Read `comma3.txt`
- The `%` is shorthand for `for each line`
- Return a formatted line similar to `printf "%-10s %-14s %-19s etc."` using `line.split(",")` for the string arguments

There's probably a `Write-Content` command for powershell, but it was easier just to have the command console redirect the output of powershell.  If you're working with very large csv files and this command works too slowly, `Write-Content` might be worth investigating.

Comment: Loaded Powershell. Copied that aboe line into the PS console and tried to run it but rcvd syntax errors. Basically leading with answer.txt halts the process...

Comment: @Stumped - That's because it's a `cmd` console command, not a `powershell` shell command.  Just open a `cmd` window and paste the line at the command prompt.  The line basically launches `powershell`, executes one command, and immediately exits.  From a `cmd` prompt, you can run `powershell` cmdlets by calling `powershell "cmdlet here"`, but still be in your `cmd` environment.  Does that make sense?

Comment: TADA! Worked like a charm. I was dropping the '>' that preceded answer.txt. I thought it was part of the display and I didn't think a PS command would start with the name of the target text file. That sucker works! It will be the basis for my PS self-tutorial.

Comment: Since I have been programming longest in the batch environment I am going to give PW the nod but you have set the PS fire inside me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO on
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cls

:: loop through records
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (comma3.txt) do (
set var=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
REM  The double comma is a problem without a good solution
REM     so if the last token is null, drop it and indent. 
if '%%f' == '' set var=%%a %%b %%c          %%d %%e
REM  !'s should be used with ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo !var! >> answer.txt
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Rojos answer, I created an excel macro that used column widths on line 1, exported the file as csv, the called powershell to convert to space delimited like so:

```
runCommand = "echo Please Wait . . . "
```

'Change to correct drive and directory:

```
runCommand2 = Left(SaveDirectory, 2) <br>
runCommand3 = "cd " & SaveDirectory<br>
```

'remove " marks that excel may insert

```
 runCommand7 = "powershell ""(get-content '" & SaveDirectory & "\" &     SaveName & ".csv" & "') -replace('""""','') | out-file '" & SaveDirectory & "\" & SaveName & "2.csv'"""
```

'Loop through cells on first row of spreadsheet to create powershell command with correct column widths

```
runCommand4 = "powershell ""Get-Content '" & SaveName & "2.csv'" & " | %{'"

x = 1
c = 0

Do Until Cells(1, x) = ""
    runCommand4 = runCommand4 & "{" & c & ",-" & Cells(1, x).Value & "}"
    x = x + 1
    c = c + 1

Loop

runCommand4 = runCommand4 & "' -f $_.split(',')} | Out-File Answer2.txt"""

runCommand5 = "cls"
runCommand6 = "pause"
```

Delete the rows with column widths so that they are not exported:

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Find and replace any commas and tabs as these may cause issues:

```
Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=Chr(9), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Save the workbook as CSV:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveDirectory & "\" & SaveName, FileFormat _
    :=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Pass all the commands to cmd

```
Call Shell("C:\Windows\System32\cmd /c" & runCommand & "&" & runCommand2 & "&" & runCommand3 & "&" & runCommand7 & "&" & runCommand4 & "&" & runCommand6, vbNormalFocus)

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

This may be a convenient solution if you import your csv to excel.