# Batch file to convert quote-enclosed .csv to fixed width columns

Tags: batch-file

I have been tasked with getting data output from a handheld scanner into a legacy application.  The scanner program does not give me any options for formatting output.

I have researched and played with this, but my DOS scripting experience is limited.  I found this on your site:

[Batch file convert comma delimited to fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670257/batch-file-convert-comma-delimited-to-fixed-length)

but it fails due to the quote-marks; and it does not have the capability to space fill to a desired column width.

The Input file below is what comes from the scanner.  The Desired Output is what I need it to look like for the legacy application.  The'|' ending each line is not desired.  I used it to indicate there are trailing spaces. The output is 8 characters, a comma, then 14 characters; left justified; space filled to the right.

I have another file that has three columns 8,14,14.

Basically, I need to go from .csv to fixed width fields separated by commas.

Input:

```
"20009","01138913"
"20009","01138915"
"20009","01138916"
"20009","01138914"
"20009","01138918"
"20009","01138920"
"20009","01138919"
```

Desired output:

```
20009   ,01138913      |
20009   ,01138915      |
20009   ,01138916      |
20009   ,01138914      |
20009   ,01138918      |
20009   ,01138910      |
20009   ,01138919      |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following, which should also be robust for columns without quotation marks:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%x in (test.csv) do call :process %%x %%y
goto :eof

:process
    set "A=%~1        "
    set "B=%~2              "
    set "A=%A:~0,8%"
    set "B=%B:~0,14%"
    (echo %A%,%B%)
```

There are a few tricks here. First `for /f` can be used to sort-of parse CSV. We get around the quotes by passing the two column values to a subroutine. As parameters can be quoted or not and we use `%~1` to access them, which removes quotes if present, the quotes pose no problem here. `%A%` and `%B%` are set to the column values with lots of padding space to the right and the following two lines select the value with the appropriate padding. Then we simply output the lines one by one.

To get an output file, simply redirect into a new file, or add `>> out.txt` to the last line.

However, if at all you can use other tools, then by all means do so. E.g. in PowerShell this would be fairly trivial:

1. Parse the file

   ```
   Import-Csv test.csv -Delimiter ',' -Header A,B |
   ```
2. Output, using a format string

   ```
     ForEach-Object { '{0,-8},{1,-14}' -f $_.A,$_.B } |
   ```
3. Write to a new file

   ```
     Out-File out.txt -Encoding Default
   ```

Comment: I know the instructions say don't use the comments to say "Thank you", but thank you, @Joey, for your very quick, very concise, and perfect solution. The explanation you included made it simple for me to amend it for the other two files.  Wish I had contacted stackoverflow before I struggled with it myself.  Thanks again.  adaniel

Comment: One random note, as sachadee added a half-working answer: There is not necessarily a need for a subroutine. The same can be done with delayed expansion inside a single block that is used in the `for`. Seasoned batch programmers won't care either way, but I guess both approaches have their pitfalls for the uninitiated beginner. It would make the quote handling less confusing though. `%%~x` can indeed be used directly for removing quotes if present. However, to pass special characters successfully to the subroutine we have to add quotes again anyway, making the whole exercise a bit moot here.